# Finding past dates with PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, date

I am currently working on a PowerShell script that will audit Active Directory Users and find the ones with past expiration dates.  The dates are in a CSV file from the HR department in an "MM/dd/yyyy" format.  I'm trying to write a script that will compare today's date with the date in the CSV file.  If the date from the CSV is past the current date, then that user needs to be disabled.

for example:

```
$today = getdate -format "MM/dd/yyyy"

$expiration = $_.'Expiration Date'

if ($today -ge $expiration) {*disable user*} else {*expiration date not 
expired*}
```

This method gives me inaccurate data.  I think Powershell is reading the dates as regular numbers, not *month/day/year*.  Does anybody know the correct way to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: try converting the data from the csv to a date time.  Something like this :-

$expiration = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.'expration date', "dd/MM/yyyy", $null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you are comparing two string values, not 2 datetime objects.

Using the format switch instructs Get-Date to return a string value.
You want to leave it as a [datetime] object to compare it reliably.

to get the current date-time you can use [datetime]::now or simply get-date (no arguments)

To cast your data from the CSV just use [datetime]$($.'expiration date')

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I was able to make it work with this code:                       foreach ($user in $users) {  
$termdate = [datetime]$($user.'Termination Date - Current')
$current_date = Get-Date 
if ($current_date -ge $termdate) {write-host "term date past - $termdate"} else {write-host "date not past - $termdate"}
}

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is parsing the csv dates from literal string object in the format what you want.

```
$Expired_Date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.'expration date', "dd/MM/yyyy", $null)
```

Use the logic now:

```
$Current_Date = Get-Date -format "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

## If date is greater than current date, disable the aduser

```
If($Current_Date -ge $Expired_Date)
{
#Get the user name. You have not mentioned how you are getting the users' list
Disable-ADAccount -Identity "CN=UserName,OU=L1Engineers,OU=UserAccounts,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM"
Write-Output "Account has been disabled for the user Username"
}
else
{
Write-Output "Account has not been expired"
}
```

Note: If you have a list of users, then you should use *foreach* loop to iterate each user and gonna do the checksum inside the loop.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this code and it still gave me inaccurate data.  Here is some of the code I used: foreach ($user in $users) {
Try {   
$termdate = [datetime]::ParseExact($user.'Termination Date - Current',"MM/dd/yyyy",$null)
$current_date = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
if ($current_date -ge $termdate) {write-host "term date past - $termdate" -ForegroundColor Yellow} else {write-host "date not past - $termdate" -ForegroundColor Green}
} catch {}
}                 - Am I missing something? ...thanks for the help!

Comment: @Leah_CyberPadawan: You already did that in Wayne's comment. Cheers :)